# Browser parsers vs Stand-alone parsers

Tags: html, libraries, browser, parsing

Firefox/Chromium have well implemented(?) parsers. Then why are parsers like lxml and other such parsers being developed with so much effort put into it?

Aren't they re-inventing the wheel? Or are they solving a different problem? Can't parsers in browsers be made into standalone libraries?

Comment: People down-voting should really read what a specific site stands for: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/about, or at least think a little.

Comment: I amn't sure about the question. But one possible answer would be that Firefox/Chromium just don't parse HTML/XML alone; they parse CSS and JavaScript too (and other plugins) for processing. And XML isn't just used on the web alone. Its a data interchange format and there are separate technologies to deal with it (there are XML databases). So a full-fledged XML parser is necessary to deal with non-browser data. You might now ask why not abstract the XML of the browser. Good question but need to go through the technical docs to understand whether its possible.

Answer (score 6):

[lxml](http://lxml.de/) is not a new parser, it's a Python binding for [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) and [libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/xslt/). Both libraries were originally build for [Gnome](http://www.gnome.org/), have been around for quite a while and are used by numerous projects, either directly or via language specific bindings like lxml.

Chrome uses both (check `chrome://credits/`) and Firefox uses [Expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/)<sup>1</sup> (check: `about:license`) which similarly to libxml is a standalone library. Both browsers use standalone open source libraries that are quite popular, so there isn't really much re-inventing the wheel going on here.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Thanks Wladimir Palant</sub>

Comment: Firefox uses the Expat parser for XML parsing, see `about:license`. As to XSLT - it seems to be an own development.

Comment: I do know what lxml is and its history, as I am working with it now. After reading: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/, it got me thinking the relative merits of parsers used in browsers and the other libraries.

Comment: @AbyCodes Well if you knew lxml is not a parser, then I really don't understand your question....

Comment: @Yanni Rizos : 'lxml is not a new parser'. Your answer too paints a broad stroke, doesn't it? let's not be too pedantic here, and see the question for what it is; which is the relative merits and the 'why' of parsers in browers vs the other parsers, or 'toolkits' that make use of it.

Comment: @AbyCodes I still don't get it. lxml is a binding toolkit, the only thing it does is offer a Python binding for libxml, which is the same parser Chrome uses. Firefox uses Expat, another widely used library, there isn't such a thing as a "browser parser", at least not when we are discussing open source browsers.

Comment: This answer is wrong. libxml2 and Expat are only xml parsers - which is entirely different and much simpler than parsing html, especially wild html. The question is legitimate and I, too, would like to know what the larger browsers are using to parse html, so why has this answer 5 upvotes?